# Lebesgue integrable for function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$,
$$f (x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 
\frac{x^2}{(e^x-1)^2} & x> 0\\
0 & x \leq 0\end{array}\right.$$

Can the function be integrated Lebesgue in the measure space $(\mathbb{R}, M, m)$? Also write the $\int f dm $
integral as a function containing the expression $\sum_{n=0}^∞ 1/n^3$. (Guidance: $1 / (1-t) ^ 2 = \sum_{n=0}^∞ 1/(nt^{n-1})$, use the series expansion $| t | <1$.)
$(\mathbb{R}, M, m)$ is a set of real numbers and a set of measurable functions, and m is a measure function.

Comment: It's spelled "integrable".

Comment: I think I know what you mean when you write $M$ and $m$.  How would I *know* that I know what you mean?

Comment: It is not too hard to show that for $x \ge 0$ we have ${x^2 \over (e^x-1)^2} \le e^{-x}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula for $\frac 1 {(1-t)^{2}}$ given in the hint is false. The series there does not even converge. The correct formula is $\frac   1 {(1-t)^{2}} = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} n t^{n-1}$

For $x>0$ we can write $f(x)=\frac {x^{2}e^{-2x}} {(1-e^{-x})^{2}}$. Using the formula $\frac   1 {(1-t)^{2}} = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} n t^{n-1}$ this becomes $f(x)=x^{2}e^{-2x}  \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} n e^{-(n-1)x}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}  x^{2} e^{-(n+1)x} $. I will let you finish by integrating term by term and using integration by parts for $\int_0^{\infty} x^{2}e^{-(n+1)x}dx$.